# Expanding an array by storing the next element right after the end of the previous array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

Say you have an array of size 13. Imagine there is no contiguous available memory section for storing an array of size 14; copying the original array into a new one is not an option. So the only way of extending the array by one element while keeping the first 13 elements the same is to store the 14th element at the very next memory address after the 13th element. How would I go about doing this, if this memory slot was available? Dynamic memory addressing?

Comment: I think you should study how [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) is [typically implemented](http://thispointer.com/what-is-stddeque-and-how-deque-works-internally/)... You should be able to get a rough idea of how to go about yours.

Comment: "How would I go about doing this, if this memory slot was available?" How would you know if there's an available memory slot? Please show some code.

Comment: I'm not saying I know this, I'm just saying if there was no available contiguous memory section for an array of size 14 for creating a new array, because then I would have to do it this way. You can verify that this is the case by trying to dynamically allocate the new array and checking if it returns an error.

Comment: @Måns Nilsson The actual implementation of memory model is not defined by standard, so availability of that memory purely depends on platform. It should be considered unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard C++ methods. standard library usually have defined realloc(), but on most platforms it all it does that  is call of another malloc() and memcpy() to copy memory. You may want to use standard library containers which hide that mechanism - that's most common - or use memory pool object (allocate all possibly required memory, then "allocate" objects within it), that's less common, usually applied for FEMA or image-processing or in OpenGL render engines.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest take array's length and insert data in length + 1 location.
eg :

```
int arraylength = abc.length;
abc[arraylength + 1].value = "Your Value";
```

Comment: But this memory slot hasn't formally been initialized/allocated, so it could get replaced by a future dynamic memory allocation during the same execution.

Comment: that's memory corruption action. Also there is no such thing as length  field or method in C++